# Check version of running JAR Linux service

Tags: java, linux, service, jar, version

I have an initctl service running a JAR which I need to ensure is restarted after the code is updated.

I know I could just write to a text file with a version and check that, but I was wondering **if there was a way to build a JAR with a version label that I could view when using initctl status ServiceNameHere?**

Any better alternatives would also be helpful!

Comment: How did you build the jar flie?

Comment: Put the version in the Specification-Version attribute of the .jar file’s manifest.

Comment: @aksappy gradle

Comment: @VGR but then how would I check that with initctl?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me yet. Did you mean you need a jar file like this <JAR_FILE_NAME>_<VERSION>.jar ?

Comment: @aksappy no I don't care about the jar's name, I'm wondering how it would be possible to know that initctl restarted the service with the new jar running instead of the old one

Comment: Where do you need to do this check?  In a shell script?

Comment: @VGR yeah exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A properly built .jar has its version stored in its manifest or module descriptor.  A .jar file is actually just a zip file, with one or more special Java-specific entries, the most important of which is `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, a plain text file known as the manifest containing information about the .jar file’s contents.

There are several [standard attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/jar/Attributes.Name.html) which may be present (though custom attributes are allowed and in fact are common).  One of the standard ones is `Implementation-Version`.

So, to determine the version of a .jar file, you can use:

```
unzip -p /path/to/jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | sed -n -e 's/^Implementation-[Vv]ersion: //p'
```

If your .jar file is a Java 9+ module, manifest attributes are ignored, so the above won’t work.  In that case, you’ll need to extract the module descriptor:

```
jar -d -f /path/to/jar | sed -n -e 's/^[^@]*@\([^ ][^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

To check whether the .jar you’re about to run has the same version as the last .jar that was run, store it somewhere under `/var`.  For instance:

```
versionfile=/var/local/last_jar_version

version=`unzip -p /path/to/jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | sed -n -e 's/^Implementation-[Vv]ersion: //p'`
# For modules: version=`jar -d -f /path/to/jar | sed -n -e 's/^[^@]*@\([^ ][^ ]*\).*/\1/p'`

if [ -f "$versionfile" && "$version" = `cat "$versionfile"` ]
then
    echo Running same version of jar as last time.
else
    echo Running a different jar version: "$version"
fi

printf %s "$version" > "$versionfile"
```

Corner case: Since [a line in a manifest may not be longer than 72 bytes (not characters)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#notes-on-manifest-and-signature-files), this will fail for non-module jar versions longer than 48 ASCII characters.  (`Implementation-Version:` is 24 bytes, and 72 − 24 = 48.)   I have never seen one that long, but I suspect they’re out there.